# TextBox content vertical stretch to available size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My goal is a TextBox that accepts return but only shows 4 lines of text that is alligned to other lines of text, but I'm having some problems that basically seem to boil down to the question:  *What is the correct way to get the content of a `TextBox` to vertically stretch to the available space?*

A minimal example looks like this:

```
<Window      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="150">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="1" />
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="2" />
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="3" />
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Content="4" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" MaxLines="4" Text="1&#13;2&#13;3&#13;4" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But the output is not what I expected:

[image: wrong streching example 1]

I tried setting the `LineHeigt`, but it only "cuts off" the text:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" MaxLines="4" Text="1&#13;2&#13;3&#13;4" TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="MaxHeight" TextBlock.LineHeight="18" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

[image: wrong streching example 2]

---

*edit*
Setting a fixed height for the `TextBox` corrects the behaviour, but that's not really a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `VerticalAlignment` of the `TextBox` to `Stretch`? This should stretch to fit the grid height

Comment: Yes, I did. I updated the example to make that clear.

Comment: OK. One other thing to try quickly: Try setting the `ScrollViewer.VerticalAlignment` (or possibly `ScrollViewer.VerticalContentAlignment`) to `Stretch`. Do this within your `TextBox` control's markup, like this: `<TextBox ... ScrollViewer.VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ...>` or `<TextBox ... ScrollViewer.VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ...>`

Comment: Do you wanna to increase text size is the empty space(vertically) is exist?

Comment: @GeoffJames That's impossible, as the designer tells me that the property 'VerticalAlignment' is set more than once.

Comment: @Gromy No, the text size should not increase, as it is already the same size as that of the other lines.

Comment: @causaprima Then that's because you've duplicated setting the `VerticalAlignment` of the TextBox itself. Did you set it on the `ScrollViewer` attached property of the `TextBox`? `<TextBox ... ScrollViewer.VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >` like I suggested?

Comment: @GeoffJames "The attachable property 'VerticalAlignment' was not found in type 'ScrollViewer'"

Comment: @causaprima OK, my bad - sorry about that. Always worth a go. Been a while since I've used WPF. Sorry I couldn't be any more help

Answer (score 1):

The immediate reason for your current issue is because you're using `Label` instead of `TextBlock`

The issue this causes is that `TextBox` renders lines as `TextBlock` which is a framework element. Whereas `Label` is a templated control inheriting from `ContentControl` and has a `Padding` set by default within it.

So if you you want them to align in your scenario you've got some options such as;

Curb the padding on your `Label`'s;

```
<Label Padding="0"/>
```

Or swap them for good old `TextBlock` (which by the way is a "lighter" control and suggested instead unless using `Label` is actually necessary).

Or you could adjust your `TextBox` to reflect the padding of your `Label`'s by targeting `TextBlock` with attached properties like `TextBlock.LineHeight` and `TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"` which would take some tinkering to get the exact output you want.

**Also keep in mind** `TextBox` is also a templated control with an embedded `ScrollViewer` so there will be a 1px offset for the default `BorderThickness`

So keeping your original control pairs if we do something like this instead, you'll see the culprit as example;

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Label Content="1" Padding="0"/>
      <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="2" Padding="0"/>
      <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="3" Padding="0"/>
      <Label Grid.Row="3" Content="4" Padding="0"/>
      <TextBox BorderThickness="0" 
               Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
               AcceptsReturn="True" MaxLines="4" 
               Text="1&#10;2&#10;3&#10;4" />
</Grid>
```

Giving the result of;

[image]

### Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Yeah this sounds good but I tried it with the `LineHeight`: `<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" MaxLines="4" Text="1&#13;2&#13;3&#13;4" Block.LineHeight="{Binding ElementName=test, Path=ActualHeight}" />`
But this does not work because the `TextBox` does not fill, do you have any suggestion for this?
The `test` is a name for one `Label`

Comment: @KevinWallis Hah ya, exactly why I eluded it would take some tinkering (which unfortunately I don't have time for since paid work pays the bills, I figured pointing the right direction and workaround would suffice). Too many nuances to figure for baseline between qualified doubles and details in Font family, size, weight, stretch, etc. Could easily grow into an article explanation that could take hours to create at which point it would be far too broad for SO Q&A format imo. If the OP deems the answer insufficient I'd have to reluctantly withdraw and delete just for time consideration.

Comment: Or in other words, typography stuff can quickly become a real pain in the @#$ if you don't work with it in depth all the time lol.

Comment: Yeah for sure :D I only tried it and the `TextBox` was not sized correct and tried a lot. Also by using Snoop I couldn't find a correct way.

Answer (score 1):

A textbox could be stretched if it is inside a viebox, like this:

```
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" >
        <TextBox Name="textBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Text="1&#13;2&#13;3&#13;4"/>
    </Viewbox>
```

But in similar condition, I'd like to use a `DataGrid`

Comment: A viewbox wouldn't be suggested for this scenario since it would result in the text sizes to not match that of the Labels/TextBlocks outside of it as it renders to fit the area.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the **Textbox** into **Grid** and set his **MaxHeight** to *Infinity* and his Height Value from that Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="ValueTextBoxGrid" Grid.Row="1">
  <TextBox       
          MaxHeight="Infinity"
          Text="Your Text"
          TextWrapping="Wrap"
          Height="{Binding ElementName=ValueTextBoxGrid, 
                     Path=ActualHeight}" />
</Grid>
```